# Null pointer Exception in java while finding no of values in given range in val tree

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, avl-tree

I am trying to print no of  node values in a given range in an avl tree .But when I try to run the program I get NullPointerException.  I couldn't get much help from previous questions of same topic.How can i correct it here.Here's my code of that portion:

```
public void range(int low, int up){
    if(low >up){
        System.out.println("Illegal input");
    }

    if(this.root != null){
        System.out.println(rangeS(this.root,low,up) +"");
    }

}

public static int rangeS(AvlNode root,int k1 ,int k2){
    int c = 0;
    if(root.key >= k1 && root.key <= k2){
        c = c+1;
    }
    if(root.key > k1 ){
        rangeS(root.left,k1,k2);
    }

    if(root.key <k2){
        rangeS(root.right,k1,k2);
    }
    return c;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are calling `rangeS` recursivly,`root.left` or/and `root.right` may be `null`. This will result in a `NPE` when `root.key` is accessed. Chech for `null` and return `0` prior to call `rangeS`.

```
public static int rangeS(AvlNode root,int k1 ,int k2){

  if(root == null) {
     return 0;
  }
  ...
}
```

Update:

To count the number of vertices under the tree, add the result of `rangeS` to your counter `c`, e.g. `c += rangeS(...)`.

Comment: one more thing I can't get the correct answer for the above code.Please help.